# SQL query to calculate average data

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite DB and I want to compress some data from a temperature readings. The readings are recorded every minute.
I have no problem to calculate this on a daily base with

```
"SELECT date(Time_T), AVG(reading) AS reading_avg, MIN(reading) AS reading_min, MAX(reading) AS reading_max FROM readings  WHERE (Zeitpunkt_T > '2016-02-20') GROUP BY (SELECT date(Time_T))"
```

That works pretty fine and gives me daily averages together with min & max. But this compression is too much. I would like to have values per hour. How can I calculate this ?

Answer (score 4):

> I would like to have values per hour

It looks like you would like to group by the hour.

To get hours in sqlite, use the `strftime` function and pass in `%H` as the formatter.

```
SELECT date(Time_T), AVG(reading) AS reading_avg, MIN(reading) AS reading_min, 
       MAX(reading) AS reading_max 
FROM readings  
WHERE (Zeitpunkt_T > '2016-02-20') 
GROUP BY strftime("%H", date);
```

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: Thank you. That solved my issue. To group the different days by hours I added  "GROUP BY date(Time_T), strftime("%H", Time_T);"